# Script to check if a program is running correctly

Tags: bash, scripts, python

I have two python programs running on two different screens. In a third screen I want to run a script which checks if the both python programs are running and also if they are running correctly (maybe check console output to determine if the output is as expected). How can I do something like this with a shell script?

```
#!/bin/sh

program1="$(ps -ef | grep '[p]ython my_program1.py' | awk '{print $2}')"
program2="$(ps -ef | grep '[p]ython my_program2.py' | awk '{print $2}')"

if [ "${program1}" != "" ]
then
        echo "Program1 is running"
else
        echo "Program1 is not running"
fi

if [ "${program2}" != "" ]
then
        echo "Program2 is running"
else
        echo "Program2  is not running"
fi
```

This is what I have right now. I think its not the best way but it should be ok for me. In program1 and program2 are the PIDs from the processes, if they are running. How can I get the live output from them to check if the lines contain given values?

Comment: Running correctly how ? What things should  be expected if the program runs incorrectly ?

Comment: Also, get rid of `ps -ef | . . .` stuff, there's too much unnecessary parsing and 3 processes involved.  Use `pgrep -f 'my_program1.py'`.   `pgrep` is designed specifically for returning PID of a process if there is one with matching command-line argument.  Single program that does the job of 3 pipes you had

Answer (score 1):

Redirect your scripts `stdout` to a file, something like:

```
my_program1.py > /tmp/log.1
```

Then in your script read the `log.1` to see if it's as it should be.

If you want to see your scripts output on the terminal they're running at, then instead of redirecting the output to a file use `tee`.

```
my_program1.py | tee /tmp/log.1
```

Comment: I think thats not so good, because the programs should run 24/7 on my server and sometimes I want check if they are still running. And then the file would get pretty large.

Comment: You can use `fifo` files instead of regular file. you can also make these files empty time to time, e.g: `sleep 10000; echo > /tmp/log.1`.